# Is it possible to change %esp

Tags: c, multithreading, assembly, x86, operating-system

```
int main()
{
   int *stackArray = calloc(15, sizeof(int));

   asm volatile ( "movl %0, %%esp  \t\n"
       : 
       : "r" (stackArray)
       : );

   return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling this by using `gcc -m32`

But when I running the program it gives 
`segmentation fault (core dump)`
I want to context switch the threads but I'm finding above error when I'm trying to point `%esp` to other array.

Comment: Hint: There is a `ret` instruction (for `return 0;`) shortly after your inline assembly. What does `ret` do?

Comment: Hint: switching stack under the compiler in a C function is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: Why would you expect anything other than an access violation after moving 0 into the stack pointer?

Comment: @user3344003 it does not move a `0`. It moves `%0` which is operand `0` which in turn is a register holding `stackArray`. So at least that part is not wrong ;)

Comment: @immibis 'return 0' is a exit status of the application. '0' use to show the success status of program. If you are talking about ret instruction than it simply pop the instruction address from the stack and jump to that address to start execute.

Comment: @Jester, I want to context switch the thread therefore I need %ESP(stack pointer register) to point to the stack pointer address that is stored in Thread Control Block.

Comment: @IshanVarade I know what `return 0;` does and I know what `ret` does. The compiler translates `return 0;` into assembly code. It probably translates it into something like `mov $0, eax` followed by `ret`. Which then pops the return address off the stack at the location pointed to by `esp`. But wait, there's just garbage there, not a return address!

Comment: Then you must be completely unaware that `ret` is going to use the address *on the top of the stack* to return... but you have just pointed the stack pointer somewhere else entirely and that stack contains a big fat zero on the top (`calloc`)

Comment: I kinda want to downvote this for failure to understand the answer, but that's not a problem with the question, just the asker.  Maybe single-stepping instructions in a debugger (`layout asm` and `stepi` in gdb) will help you see   what's going on.  See more on the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes it is. When compiling some c method using the -O0 flag you'll see

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
...
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret
```

Wait a minute. . . It is restored before ret. You error is precisely why even the compiler doesn't touch esp without saving ^^

Comment: That code is backwards.  Maybe you meant to use AT&T syntax?  In Intel syntax where the destination is the first operand, `mov esp, ebp` to set ESP equal to EBP goes at the *bottom*, in the epilogue, pointing the stack pointer at the saved frame pointer.  Also, compilers only do this *without* `-O3`; in modern gcc/clang/msvc/icc, `-fomit-frame-pointer` or equivalent is on by default at `-O1` or `-O2`.

Comment: Yep, i usually use NASM syntax but looked at a bunch of AT&T questions before that one, that wrapped my brain around - almost the same goes for the O number, i really should stop answering after frying my brain for 8 hours xD

Comment: Ok, now the code makes sense, but the code you show doesn't actually modify ESP, except for restoring it.  If the `...` portion doesn't modify ESP, then ESP already equals EBP before `mov esp, ebp` runs.  (So compilers will typically omit that instruction and just use `pop ebp` in functions where they didn't `sub esp, 16` or accumulate some pushed function args that they haven't popped yet or whatever.)